# How to create a mule 4.3 copy book of flat file for complex data structure?

Tags: java, transform, mule-studio, mule4, copybook

Need to read a fixed length file and transform it into a java object.
Can anyone help to create a mule 4.3 copy book for below data structure transformation?

```
Header   headerValue2headerValue3headerValue4headerValue5
T_Level1 T_Level1Val1T_Level1Val2T_Level1Val3T_Level1Val4
T_Level2 T_Level2Val1T_Level2Val2T_Level2Val3T_Level2Val4
T_Level2 T_Level2Val1T_Level2Val2T_Level2Val3T_Level2Val4
T_Item   T_ItemVal1T_ItemVal12T_ItemVal13T_ItemVal14
T_ItemL2 T_ItemL2Val1T_ItemL2Val2T_ItemL2Val3T_ItemL2Val4
T_Vat    T_VatVal1T_VatVal12T_VatVal13T_VatVal14
T_Item   T_ItemVal1T_ItemVal12T_ItemVal13T_ItemVal14
T_Vat    T_VatVal1T_VatVal12T_VatVal13T_VatVal14
T_LeveL1 T_Level1Val1T_Level1Val2T_Level1Val3T_Level1Val4
T_LeveL2 T_ItemL2Val1T_ItemL2Val2T_ItemL2Val3T_ItemL2Val4
T_Item   T_ItemVal1T_ItemVal12T_ItemVal13T_ItemVal14
T_Vat    T_VatVal1T_VatVal12T_VatVal13T_VatVal14
Trailer  TraileValue1TraileValue2TraileValue3TraileValue4
```

Sample object structure is as below

[image: sample object structure]

Comment: To implement a transformation you need to understand the input, the output and the transformation rules (how to map the output from the input). Your question is not clear on that. Additionally, What have you tried? What failed? Also share examples of inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs or errors.